# Query slow on subscriber but fast on publisher (Merge Replication)

Tags: sql-server, replication, performance, merge-replication, query-performance

As the title suggests, I am having issues with performance with my subscriber. I run the exact same query (it's a recursive query with a few joins but nothing too serious). I can run this query on my publisher in under 1s but it takes over 30s on the subscriber.

Things I've taken into account so far:

- This is the only subscriber
- The two servers are practically identical in terms of computing power (in fact the sub has more firepower).
- The indexes are the same on both but the publisher has an MSmerge_index (which I think should only exist on the publisher).
- It's a partial merge but this subscriber doesn't have filtered articles (in other words it has the full data set) so the traffic should be identical besides users running select queries (only 30 users online right now with infrequent requests)

I have duplicated my environment onto development servers and see the same results (slow subscriber, fast publisher).

Is there anything I can do to improve this performance? Some index or modification? Or is this something that I have to live with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you upload the actual execution plans for fast and slow queries (you can use pastebin to upload the plan xmls) ? Are the stats updated on subscriber - where query is running slow ?

Comment: Working on it :) I am renaming any company specific stuff, database names, tables, etc.

Comment: You can use plan explorer to obfuscate information from plan.. if that helps !

Comment: Slow: http://pastebin.com/j5g9GxzX
Fast: http://pastebin.com/EhVNL3sY

Comment: Notepad++ for the win ;)

Comment: seems like I cant see the fast one - `This is a private paste.`

Comment: My bad: Fast: http://pastebin.com/nCzTwZB2

Comment: From the execution plans, in the slower one I am seeing `remote query` as the most expensive operator and there is no `remote query` operator in the faster execution plan. Are the stats updated on the subscriber ? Also, can you make sure that both pub and subscriber have same indexes ?

Comment: Sorry, newbie question: what do you mean by 'are the stats updated on the subscriber?'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32425/discussion-between-kin-and-tmwoods).